# How to make a dynamic permission system in PHP

Tags: php

For an application I'm building I need some kind of permission system. I want to build it myself. Now there are a couple of options.

- Access control list
- Role based system
- Group based

I find ACL a bit over the top, role based only really works if you know your resources and groupbased is what I'm leaning towards, however I have an issue.

I have a system where **Users** can *Edit* artists (i.e. **Superfans**), all users who are eglible for this will go into some kind of **group/role**. But how do I (this is where the dynamic parts comes into play) appoint them to single artists? I was thinking of just 5 people per artist.

So basically; **I need a group-based permission system that allows user-based permissions as well.**

Writing that it feels like I need ACL, but I can't make resources like: can_edit_u2, can_edit_bonjovi, can_edit_thebeatles.. or can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply explained with table structure:

**users**

```
id |    username    |
1  |    John        |
2  |    Michael     |
```

**Artists**

```
id |    name        |
1  |    Bon Jovi    |
2  |    Beatles     |
```

**can_edit**

```
id |    artist_id   |    user_id    |
1  |    1           |    1          |
2  |    1           |    2          |
3  |    2           |    2          |
```

Your scripting logic should interpret this like - John can edit Bon Jovi, but Michael can edit both Bon Jovi and Beatles.

For example if John is logged on, it should store session variable with its user_id -> `$_SESSION['id'] = 1`.

Then the user is about to edit Beatles.
Your logic checks:

```
SELECT tb1.name, tb2.user_id
FROM artists AS tb1.
INNER JOIN can_edit as tb2
ON tb1.id = tb2.artist_id
WHERE tb1.name = 'Beatles'


name    |    user_id   |
Beatles |     2        |
```

So you have now some code where fetching the results in PHP.

```
if ($_SESSION['id'] == $row['user_id']) {  // if the output of the session variable (1) is equal to the output of the query (2)
... // allow editing
}
else {
... // don't allow
}
```

In this example $_SESSION['id'] is not equal to $row['user_id'], so it won't let John to edit Beatles

Comment: Yeah, but Artist is just one example. Even though I can't think of something right now, I'm probably gonna need more 'items' like artist. So I don't really want to hardcode artist_id into a table..

Comment: It's not hardcoding. It depends on the dynamic's of your code. In each case you should have for your items (artists) each name and id in a single table. Your assign-role controller (i.e. admin panel) should take care of inserting artist_id and user_id in `can_edit` table. For example you have a query witch have fetched results from both tables users and artists. You choose user John and in a drop down are populated all artists from `artists` table, that are not assigned to `John`. So you choose an artist from it, and click Save. A query is triggered which inserts John and artist_id in table